# Regex patern to match dimensions from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I've searched for 3 hours already and couldn't find anything that doesn't deal with only a single pattern.

I use a dimensions parameter in a URL (i.e. ...media.php?sid=200x100&mid=... where 200 is width and 100 is height).  There are other parameters that may/may not include other numbers (i.e. UUID's) but are not important to this task but should not affect the pattern match.

What I need to do is match the 'sid=###x###' portion only in order to replace it.  The ### should support variable length numbers in a range from 1 to say 99999.

I've tried a lot of patterns so far and suspect someone will probably know this off the top of their head so I'm not going to list ALL of my attempts, but here's the basic code I'm using:

```
var oldSid = new RegExp('sid=[0..99999]x[0..99999]');
var newSid = 'sid=500x500';
var newUrl = oldUrl.replace(oldSid, newSid);
```

Any help you can offer to fill in the blanks would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Use this one:*

```
var oldSid = new RegExp("sid=\\d{1,5}x\\d{1,5}");
```

*...or (as it's not a dynamic regular expression) this one:*

```
var newUrl = oldUrl.replace(/sid=\d{1,5}x\d{1,5}/, newSid);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The non-dynamic was a great added tidbit and what I went with.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex `sid=[0-9]{1,5}x[0-9]{1,5}` to find such match...

*Test it [here](http://ideone.com/aIv3N).*

Comment: Thanks @omega, also worked. The other answer was just a little shorter and the non-dynamic was something I should have used from the start.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: @KevinFarley - The reason why I haven't used `\\d` is that it is `\d` in non-dynamic pattern and I didn't want make you confused regarding escaping characters. Other answer came minute later with nothing new, just reformating my answer to `\\d` (resp. `\d`) code. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry @omega, I just thought he went a little over and above, the non-dynamic was helpful and I think something that other users with a similar issue might be helped by. When they're submitted so closely, you both could have been typing at the same time and not seen the others response.

Comment: @omega, I hate to break your bubble, but I did not see your answer before I submitted mine, so did not copy it.

Comment: None from me, I apologise if I came across as being nasty, have a +1 as an apology